# How could I use logrotate and group by day a bunch of gzip files with an uncompresssed extension?

Tags: linux, windows-10, shell-script, gzip, logrotate

Doing a test in a production enviroment with rotation logs with 2 days just for testing purposes with gizp files. Created a test file at /tmp/.

/etc/init.d/test

```
/tmp/test/*.gz {
       daily
       missingok
       rotate 2
       notifempty
       prerotate
         /root/log_mv.sh
       endscript
}
```

Didn't use the compress statement at /etc/init.d/test and I'm not figure out how could I group a bunch of .gz files by day and i could extract those files that are using logrotate.

My scenario is MobaXterm application into Windows 10 Pro and I need to extract these files generated by logrotate with a extension that didn't use compression.

[logrotate examples](https://www.linuxtechi.com/manage-linux-log-files-using-logrotate/)

Comment: I realize that English is probably not your first language and honestly have ***A LOT*** of respect for you but your question confuses me.  "Add a zip extension".. you mean use the ZIP format?  You mean instead of Gzip, you want old school ZIP?  You want to add a zip extension?  `mv file.gz file.zip`.. please (if you can) make your details more clear.

Comment: So if you are in linux, what you want is called a "tar ball" (because it uses `tar`).. this combines files without compressing them.  Usually, people `tar` the files first, them GZip the tar ball.. what you want is the other way around. :)

Comment: According with your reply will edit the post (let the question cleaner)... These logs are located at Linux and I realized that I can use 7zip for a tgz file, but did not catch how could I do the whole task... Point me out if this question is clear... You are right I have .gz files and want a .tgz file that group by day.
@SeñorCMasMas

Comment: So.. first of all, I am not an expert with logrotate.  I have done a whole lot of stuff like you are trying to do though. (including using MobaXTerm)  You want first to group these logs on the Linux box by date into a single compressed file?, transfer them to windows? then decompress them from the windows side?  I am still trying to understand.  I am betting that you will need to write a bash script for this.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas Yes you are right, I'm trying to get those files compressed by gzip and group them into a single file, so I could have a tgz file (logs-2021-31-01.tgz) that I transfer to Windows and decompress by 7zip at Windows OS. I'm thinking the same that I will have to deal with bash script and put at cron job...

Comment: I have found that creating a windows share is the easiest way to go for the file transfer.  Make a stupid user (I call mine LinuxUser) in windows and give them access to a windows share you create.  Use SMB to copy the files there via cron job on a schedule.  You can make a trigger on the windows side to process the files via powershell using `FileSystemWatcher` .. in fact, if you are more comfortable with windows, you can do ALL of the work on the windows side.  No need to even compress the logs.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas Did an edit to the post to reflect what I'm thinking about by Linux side (using a bash script). But I will rethink with your last comment... At this moment tks for helping...